# Virial Shock Heating

Tags: cosmology, galaxy-cluster, hydrostatic-equilibrium

In the review paper on protoclusters, [Roderik Overzier (pg 25)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00159-016-0100-3) mentions the concept of *virial shock heating* which seems to be a process involved with galaxy cluster formation.

I'm not fully certain what a virialized galaxy cluster is apart from the fact that it's in hydrostatic equilibrium, and is one of the key distinguishing features between a protocluster and a fully formed galaxy cluster.

I vaguely understand that shock heating relates to the heating that occurs when something is travelling at supersonic speed within a medium and produces a shock.

Answer (score 2):

Virial shocks appear when gas falls in toward a galaxy, and the shocked gas stays hot so the pressure in the post-shock gas can support the shock and keep it away from the galactic disk. 
 The alternative is if the post-shock gas cools and loses pressure support, and the (non-virial) shock collapses right down to the galactic disk.  The significance is that if gas falls directly onto the high-density disk, it has different effects than if it meets a low-density shock well away from the galaxy.  There's a lot of information at https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/345/1/349/984798